# Is there a way to make Dropbox public folders read-only?

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox

I basically want to share a folder in Dropbox but I don't want that others have read-write access. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Your **public** folders are read only, your **shared** folders are r/w and there is noway to change that (yet). [See dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19)

Comment: There seems to be work going on, but not yet operational: https://www.dropbox.com/help/60/en. 
There is even a work-around mentioned, i.e. only sending links instead of creating a shared folder (which might not be what you want)

Answer (score 2):

Unforuntatelly, your shared folders are r/w. However, you can workaround that using cloudHQ.

Basically, lets suppose you want to share folder **FOLDER_TO_SHARE**. You need to create an 
extra folder (lets call it **FOLDER_TO_SHARE_READ_ONLY**) in Dropbox and then establishing cloudHQ one-way sync (and with option "override changes on target") from from **FOLDER_TO_SHARE** to **FOLDER_TO_SHARE_READ_ONLY** and then you can share **FOLDER_TO_SHARE_READ_ONLY**.

So cloudHQ will do one-way sync from **FOLDER_TO_SHARE** --> **FOLDER_TO_SHARE_READ_ONLY** so only changes from **FOLDER_TO_SHARE** will be propagated to **FOLDER_TO_SHARE_READ_ONLY**. And since you have "override changes on target" set, then any outside change on the **FOLDER_TO_SHARE_READ_ONLY** will be automatically reverted back.

[image]

Some details can be found here: 
http://blog.cloudhq.net/post/40164161550/how-to-create-read-only-dropbox-shared-folders-using